# How to prevent @ModelAttribute to instantiate a calendar in a method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a method in a controller:

```
public FormValidationResult submitFormAndSendEmail(@Valid ContactForm form, BindingResult result,
  @HttpSessionParam(value = "lastTimeContactFormSent", required = false) Calendar lastTimeContactFormSent)
```

As you can see I have created a @HttpSessionParam annotation, this will take a variable from the HttpSession and put it into the specified method parameter.

However...

Before the argument is being resolved, I recieve an InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl because calendar cannot be instantiated by a default constructor.

Using the given stacktrace, I see that the HandlerMethodInvoker within "resolveModelAttribute" is causing the instantiation.

How can i prevent this? I don't want an instantiation, I want to use my own WebArgumentResolver in order to fill the method parameter.

Any clues?

More info:
Stacktrace by Spring (3.0.4):

```
    java.lang.InstantiationException
    at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:30)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveModelAttribute(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:772)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:356)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:171)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:427)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:415)
```

I don't see the debugger hit the webargumentresolver.

The argument is defined in my application context (xml) as following:

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="customArgumentResolver" ref="sessionParamResolver"/>
</bean>  

<!--  annotation to resolve httpSession attributes -->
<bean id="sessionParamResolver" class="nl.usgpeople.vakgilde.spring.mvc.extensions.SessionParamArgumentResolver"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like axtavt was right, partially. The WebArgument did not get resolved. However, it was defined in the context xml properly. So why did'nt it work?

The application-context.xml included an mvc-context.xml , (using the import tag). Within the mvc-context.xml I had defined the bean and such.

Moving the bean definition outside mvc-context.xml , above the import tag, made Spring 'notice' the bean and resolve in the appropriate order.

Looking further, it looks like as long as my sessionParamResolver bean is defined *above* the  tag, it works. When placing my bean below this tag, it does not work.

Looking at the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html), at chapter 15.12 Configuring Spring MVC , it is said that it will define a AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter. So I guess defining it beforehand makes sure it also uses your customArgumentResolvers.

Comment: Btw, by doing this, you will override the default AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter. That is a bug in spring, see here: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?p=272494 , you need to take out the mvc:annotation-driven tag in order to gain complete control.

Comment: In Spring 3.1 this seems to be easier, you could use the mvc:annotation-driven tag and within set your own resolver (hopefully). Atleast it should work for the conversionService.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your argument resolver wasn't fired or didn't resolved the argument. Make sure that:

- your resolver is correctly passed to `AnnotationHandlerMethodAdapter`
- if your resolver is fired, it correctly resolves the argument

Comment: I've defined that in my application-context, I've updated my original question with how it is configured.